# Convert UIWebview contents to a UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I am using a UIWebView to display HTML formatted text. I am not loading a webpage, just supplying a string of HTML to the UIWebView.

Now I want to animate this UIWebView on screen, actually several of them (2-10 at a time). UIWebView is a little heavy, and although I haven't attempted it yet, I am planning for the worst. (I don't think this is premature optimization, I 'm almost positive this will be an issue)

To get around the problem, I figured I could convert the contents of the UIWebViews to UIImages and animate them instead.

So, my questions are:

1. How do you convert UIWebview
   contents to a UIImage (or
   CGImageRef)?
2. My UIWebViews have
   transparent bacgrounds, will the
   transparency be carried over to the
   UIImage?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview.bounds.size);
[webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You might run into issues if the webview dimensions are large because the webview uses a `CATiledLayer` that doesn't draw everything for memory reasons.

The image will include transparency

Comment: Thanks.My webviews are just simple single lines of text, so I don't think that will be an issue. I guess the dimensions of the image are the dimensions of the webview on screen?

Comment: You might need to call sizeToFit: after the webview loads, to get the webview the exact size of the content

Comment: just out of curiosity why do you want to display single lines of text as UIWebView?

Comment: I've asked a followup question concerning how to deal with large webview dimension.   It can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4475397/516731

Comment: now what do you do if you need to put in that image something other than the webview? turn it first to image and then aggregate or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Nice, but the resulting image, is not that crisp... I wonder if there is a way to enlarge the resolution of the image (like using something like scale = 2, so you get a more crisp image)...

Comment: Maybe this: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webview.bounds.size, NO, 0); works better...

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but if you set the cache param of CoreAnimation the OS will handle this optimisation for you.

e.g.

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:self.view cache:YES];
```

Comment: I'm doing a path animation, so I can't use UIView convenience methods, but their may be something (probably is) in CA that works simalarly...