# How to save image in photo album?

Tags: iphone

I am using GLImageProcessing sample code.I want to save modified image in photo album how it possible.please help me.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352864/how-to-get-uiimage-from-eaglview/1945733#1945733) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352864/how-to-get-uiimage-from-eaglview) for how to use glReadPixels() to extract the image from OpenGL ES within a CAEAGLLayer into a UIImage that you can store in the photos library using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum().  The standard approach of using -renderInContext: to generate a UIImage from a CALayer does not work for OpenGL ES content.