# EAGLView to UIImage color conversion issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, opengl-es, eaglview

I have an EAGLView (taken from Apple's examples) which I can successfully convert to a UIImage using this code:

```
- (UIImage *)glToUIImage:(CGSize)size {

NSInteger backingWidth = size.width;
NSInteger backingHeight = size.height;

NSInteger myDataLength = backingWidth * backingHeight * 4;

// allocate array and read pixels into it.
GLuint *buffer = (GLuint *) malloc(myDataLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

// gl renders “upside down” so swap top to bottom into new array.
for(int y = 0; y < backingHeight / 2; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < backingWidth; x++) {
        //Swap top and bottom bytes
        GLuint top = buffer[y * backingWidth + x];
        GLuint bottom = buffer[(backingHeight - 1 - y) * backingWidth + x];
        buffer[(backingHeight - 1 - y) * backingWidth + x] = top;
        buffer[y * backingWidth + x] = bottom;
    }
}

// make data provider with data.
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, myDataLength, releaseScreenshotData);

// prep the ingredients
const int bitsPerComponent = 8;
const int bitsPerPixel = 4 * bitsPerComponent;
const int bytesPerRow = 4 * backingWidth;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

// make the cgimage
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(backingWidth, backingHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, YES, renderingIntent);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

// then make the UIImage from that
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

return myImage;

}

void releaseScreenshotData(void *info, const void *data, size_t size) {
free((void *)data);
};
```

And here is the code where I use this method to convert to a UIImage:

```
EAGLView *newView = [[EAGLView alloc] initWithImage:photo.originalImage];

[newView reshapeFramebuffer];
[newView drawView:theSlider.tag value:theSlider.value];
//the two lines above are how EAGLViews in Apple's examples are modified


photoItem *newPhoto = [[photoItem alloc] initWithImage:[self glToUIImage:photo.originalImage.size]];
```

The problem I am having is, sometimes the converted UIImage won't have the same colors as the EAGLView. This occurs if I apply a high saturation to the EAGLView, or high brigtness, or low contrast, and some other cases. For example, if I apply a high saturation to the EAGLView, and then convert to UIImage, some parts of the image will be brighter than what it's suppose to be.

So I discovered that the problem was a EAGLView timing issue in disguise, similar to my previous question here ([EAGLView to UIImage timing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047639/eaglview-to-uiimage-timing-question)).

Comment: Presumably you're adjusting saturation, brightness, contrast internally to the EAGLView (so, using a shader or some other OpenGL path)?

Comment: Tommy, I am adjusting internally, I edited the post to show how I am editing the EAGLView before converting to a photoItem (which is my custom class, basically a UIImage).

Comment: I'm running short of ideas immediately then. CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB would cause a difference on the desktop since OpenGL returns in a device-dependent space and that normally returns a device-independent space but not on iOS because it varies from OS X in that area. There's obviously no byte-by-byte shuffling going on, and NULL to 'decode' should result in no remapping. Have you checked the values you're passing on as alpha? If you have a custom view to draw the UIImage is it possible you're compositing there by not clearing meaning that the UIImage is correct but is rendered incorrectly?

Comment: Tommy, I finally hacked my way into a solution. It was another EAGLView timing issue (which only showed up during Saturation actually), and I was able to fix it with your performSelector:afterDelay:0.0 approach. Thx

Comment: Please mark this question as closed (or move your answer into an answer and mark it)

Comment: I do not know how to do this, perhaps I don't have enough reputation to post a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that still cares see my comment below:

Tommy, I finally hacked my way into a solution. It was another EAGLView timing issue (which only showed up during Saturation actually), and I was able to fix it with your performSelector:afterDelay:0.0 approach. Thx

Also, I would recommend anyone coding for iOS 5.0 to look into Core Image and GLKView. They basically make your job of adjusting image properties (as I am doing here) and EAGLView to UIImage conversion type of stuff much simpler.