# Convert UIWebview contents to a UIImage when the webview is larger than the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiimage

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858788/convert-uiwebview-contents-to-a-uiimage) (and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858788/convert-uiwebview-contents-to-a-uiimage/858957#858957)), I'm trying to make an UIImage out from a webview.  So far I'm using the code suggested in the answer, specifically:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview.bounds.size);
[webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

However, when the contents of the webview are larger than the screen, the resulting images are not complete and have missing patches.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got the answer:

You have to set the frame of the Webview to the full content size just before you create the image. After this just set the size back to origin:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageFromWebView:(UIWebView *)view
{
    // tempframe to reset view size after image was created
    CGRect tmpFrame         = view.frame;

    // set new Frame
    CGRect aFrame               = view.frame;
    aFrame.size.height  = [view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size].height;
    view.frame              = aFrame;

    // do image magic
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size]);

    CGContextRef resizedContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:resizedContext];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // reset Frame of view to origin
    view.frame = tmpFrame;
    return image;
}
```

Comment: I like it so much when ppl post the answer after they got it. that's the way to flow! :)

Comment: BTW, I just wonder - why is that a singleton and not just a function? I'm asking out of curiosity as someone that still doesn't use singletons

Comment: I start to understand myself why it can't work with the '-', but how do I use the '+'?

Comment: Re "Hamutsi": What I do is to add a "category" for UIImage and declare this method for it.

Comment: i use this function and it's working perfectly in iOS 4.3 but when i run the same line of code in iOS 5 it stop working can any one help me here please :(

Answer (score 7):

D R's answer is fine. The only thing missing is taking into account the **scale** of screen. I have it corrected in my **Swift** version and it works fine for me.

```
extension UIWebView{
func snapshotForCompletePage() -> UIImage {
    // tempframe to reset view size after image was created
    let tmpFrame: CGRect = self.frame
    // set full size Frame
    var fullSizeFrame: CGRect = self.frame
    fullSizeFrame.size.height = self.scrollView.contentSize.height
    self.frame = fullSizeFrame

    // here the image magic begins
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fullSizeFrame.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    let resizedContext: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    self.layer.renderInContext(resizedContext)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    // reset Frame of view to origin
    self.frame = tmpFrame
    return image
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

@Jibeex's answer worked for me. But I had to add the following code

```
    fullSizeFrame.size.width = self.scrollView.contentSize.width
```

below

```
    fullSizeFrame.size.height = self.scrollView.contentSize.height
```

for it to fully work. Writing as answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: why not `fullSizeFrame.size =  self.scrollView.contentSize`

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([webView sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is struggling how to do this in Xamarin, based on @DR answer, here is the code:

```
var image = new UIImage();

var previousFrame = _tableView.Frame;
var newFrame = new CGRect(new CGPoint(0, 0), _tableView.ContentSize);
View.Frame = newFrame;

UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(_tableView.ContentSize, false, UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale);
var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
View.Layer.RenderInContext(context);
image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

View.Frame = previousFrame;


return image;
```