# UIBezierPath :  Incorrect retrieval of view screenshot

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, screenshot, uibezierpath

I'm taking the screenshot following way.

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot 
{
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

On UIView I'm drawing paths using `UIBezierPath`.

The screenshots that I'm getting are incorrect like this

[image]

Any ideas why the upper part is cut to blank ? On UIView all drawing is displayed correctly.

---

UPDATE : This happens when I draw a long path with `UIBezierPath` when I release the my brush and get the screenshot it gets the screenshot correctly.

Comment: Follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964153/ios-whats-the-fastest-most-performant-way-to-make-a-screenshot-programaticall

Comment: I've tried also that way, still the image is not correct. I guess the problem is how to UIBezierPath maps its data to layer

Comment: refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475397/convert-uiwebview-contents-to-a-uiimage-when-the-webview-is-larger-than-the-scre

Comment: its the same, guys do you have any alternative of using CoreGraphics ?

Answer (score 1):

I saw the another thread which you post.
According to [the apple technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010193), you need to adjust the geometry coordinate first. 
So, before render the layer of window, do following things first.

```
// -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
// so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
CGContextSaveGState(context);
// Center the context around the window's anchor point
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
// Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
// Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                      -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                      -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot :(UIView*)vw
{

    CGRect rect = [vw bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [vw.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Use This one

Comment: Basically your solution is not different from mine. The same issue exists also for taking this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)takeScreenShot:(id)sender
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size); 

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```