# iOS : Getting screenshot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Guys I'm looking for the way to retrieve the application screenshot by mean **other than CoreGraphics**.

I know that Apple has recommended to do it using `CoreGraphics` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010193)

But I have an issue by doing so when drawing on `UIView` using `UIBezierPath` which I've described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340079/uibezierpath-incorrect-retrieval-of-view-screenshot).

So does anyone know any alternative of getting the screenshot of the application by means other than `CoreGraphics`?

Comment: Why don't you just sort out the bug you have with your current code using CoreGraphics as that is the way that Apple recommend?

Comment: I'm really trying to sort it out already the second day. I really think its already iOS internal bug of incorrect mapping of UIBezierPath to UILayer. No one was able to suggest any reasonable reference. So thats why I'm looking for something other than getting BitMapContext using CoreGraphics. Unless of course if your able to suggest any other reasonable reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty mush the only way, but if really can't try guiding the user into pressing the home and power button at the same time.