# Convert tableview to image when it is longer than the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert UIWebview contents to a UIImage when the webview is larger than the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475397/convert-uiwebview-contents-to-a-uiimage-when-the-webview-is-larger-than-the-scre)

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` can convert a view to an image. But if a table-view is longer than the screen, the function can't show the whole table-view.

How can I do this?

Comment: I got The solution but it is funny one.
I put the Table view inside a scroll view. then the height for scrollview content is equal to tableview.content.size.height. then i update the size after tableview finish load. then i disable tableview scroll features. then i convert the scrollview content to UIImage. funny solution and i not suggest to use this but... it works for now :D

Comment: the height of scrollview content just put any random for start... then update it afterward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5104559/254422
Just replace the `UIWebView` with `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

This will get an image of the whole `UITableView`.

```
UIImage *image = nil;
CGRect oldFrame = self.tableView.frame;
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.contentSize.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height)];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tableView.contentSize); {
    [self.tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.tableView setFrame:oldFrame];
```

Comment: thx ,i have work it out . but i got another question. then the height of the image gets longer ,the resolution of the image will get lower .thus the image is not clear ...how could i do