# Resize UIView prior to taking a screenshot

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigraphicsimagerenderer

I'm trying to convert an `UIView` to an `UIImage` to be saved to the photo album.

Thus far, I have been able to get this, but the resultant image is based on the `UIView`'s layout on screen. (eg: Portrait or Landscape)

My goal is to have the same output (eg: Square) no matter if the `UIView` is in portrait or in landscape.

This is the current code that I'm using (I tried a lot of differing methods)

```
extension UIView {
    func image() -> UIImage {
        let imageRenderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        if let format = imageRenderer.format as? UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat {
          format.opaque = true
        }
        let image = imageRenderer.image { context in
            return layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        }
        return image
    }
}
```

I am able to change the `UIImage` dimension to the desired size, but the `UIView` still follows what its originally layout is on screen.

```
  let f = ergTrainChartView.frame;      //Grab current
  ergTrainChartView.frame = CGRect(x: f.origin.x, y: f.origin.y, width: 365, height: 365)
```

[image]

My goal is to have the left image no matter if the device is in Portrait or Landscape (iPad or iPhone) mode.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to change your code to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`? That's how I deal with resizing. If not, then maybe the issue isn't with UIImage or UIGraphics, but with drawing a UIView into a context the way you need.

Comment: @dfd I tried (and I tried again) but not working. I think this has to do w/ "what" my UIView is. It's based on ```drawRect``` and even I set ```setNeedsDisplay()``` on it, it doesn't work. What ended up working was creating another reference to the UIView eg: ```let newView = UIView()```, setting a new frame for it and copying all the data that created that view to it and using that instead. Hope it makes sense. Thanks for helping tho

Comment: I am having the same issue, although different use case. I am trying to resize a UIView and take a screen shot, then deep link the screen shot to instagram. When it's saved to Camera Roll, it looks fine. When it's deep linked to instagram, it is stretched.