# how to print a word document or html document through zebra RW420 via iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, zebra-printers

My requirement is print word document or webpage from zebra RW420 from a iphone application I don't how to proceed..Kindly help me out

thanks in advance
srividya

Comment: Looks like there is an [sdk](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/adapt-software/zebralink-sdk-apple-ipad-ipodtouch.html#mainpartabscontainer_71ac=research-learn) you can use.

Comment: how to use the sdk to print webpage for a UIwebview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Zebra SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/adapt-software/zebralink-sdk-apple-ipad-ipodtouch.html#mainpartabscontainer_71ac=research-learn) can print out images (UIImage).  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858788/convert-uiwebview-contents-to-a-uiimage) for how to convert the contents of a UIWebview to a UIImage.  Then see the `GraphicsUtil` documentation which is bundled with the SDK on how to print a UIImage